# How to improve dataframe creation from arrays in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, concatenation

I have two arrays `A` and `B` which contain a series of numbers.

My goal is to create a dataframe having the following structure:
for each element of B I want to correspond all the values of A.

For example:
if `A = [0,2,5]` and `B=[4,9,8]` I want to obtain the following pairs: `0-4,0-9,0-8`, `2-4,2-9,2-8` and `5-4,5-9,5-8`.

I was able to achieve my goal in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a, b = 1, 10
c, d = -10, -1
step = 0.5

A = np.arange(a,b,1)+step
B = np.arange(c,d,1)

df = pd.DataFrame() 
for j in B:
    for i in A:
        name = 'H'+str(int(np.abs(i)))+str(int(np.abs(j)))
        dic = {'XXX':[i],'YYY':[j],'ZZZ':name}
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(dic)],ignore_index=True)
```

Column `ZZZ` but be calculated as shown above.

The code I wrote works fine but it is pretty slow when I increase the values of `a,b,c,d`.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve my goal? I would like to avoid nested for loops and it should be a more efficient way than mine obviously.

Comment: you can combine lists using  [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) as in zip(A,B) or you could concat columns in pandas directly df.XXX.astype(str) + df.YYY.astype(str) to create the new column.

Comment: mmm I never heard about it... I  will take a look right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create all combination by [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

For column `XXX` convert `float` to `int` and then to `str` for remove decimal, fom column `YYY` get absolute value and cast to `str`:

```
from  itertools import product
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(B, A)), columns=['YYY','XXX'])
#swap columns
df = df[['XXX','YYY']]
df['ZZZ'] = 'H' + df.XXX.astype(int).astype(str) + df.YYY.abs().astype(str)

print (df.head(20))
    XXX  YYY   ZZZ
0   1.5  -10  H110
1   2.5  -10  H210
2   3.5  -10  H310
3   4.5  -10  H410
4   5.5  -10  H510
5   6.5  -10  H610
6   7.5  -10  H710
7   8.5  -10  H810
8   9.5  -10  H910
9   1.5   -9   H19
10  2.5   -9   H29
11  3.5   -9   H39
12  4.5   -9   H49
13  5.5   -9   H59
14  6.5   -9   H69
15  7.5   -9   H79
16  8.5   -9   H89
17  9.5   -9   H99
18  1.5   -8   H18
19  2.5   -8   H28
```

Comment: ok great thanks :) could you please fix the also the index sot that it goes from 0 to the end?